# How to invert Logic Gate input in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, logic

I have drawn the following circuit, but how could the inputs of a Logic Gate be inverted? (As in the scanned picture, but it does not matter which gate exactly, just generally)

[image: The circuit]

[image: The negated Inputs]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz} %vectorgraphics
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,
decorations.pathreplacing,backgrounds,calc} 
%graph/flowchart
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} \draw

(0,0) node[nand port] (nand1) {}
(3,0) node[nand port] (nand2) {}
(5,0) node[nand port] (nand3) {}

(3,2) node[nand port] (nand4) {}
(5,2) node[nand port] (nand5) {}

(3,4) node[nand port] (nand6) {}
(5,4) node[nand port] (nand7) {}

(0,4) node[nand port] (nand8) {}

(nand1.out) |- (nand2.in 2)
(nand2.out) -| node[circ,midway]{} (nand3.in 1)
(nand2.out) -| (nand3.in 2)

(nand8.out) |- (nand6.in 1)
(nand6.out) -| node[circ,midway]{} (nand7.in 2)
(nand6.out) -| (nand7.in 1)

(nand4.out) -| node[circ,midway]{} (nand5.in 2)
(nand4.out) -| (nand5.in 1)

(-2,1) node(B1)[anchor=east] {B}
(-2,1) -| node[circ,midway]{} (nand1.in 1) 
to[short,*-] (nand1.in 2)
(-2,1) -| (nand4.in 2)
(1,1) node[circ]{} |- (nand6.in 2)


(-2,3) node[anchor=east] {A}
(-2,3) -| node[circ,midway]{} (nand8.in 2) 
to[short,*-] (nand8.in 1)
(-2,3) -| (nand4.in 1)
(0.5,3) node[circ]{} |- (nand2.in 1)

(6,1.97) node[anchor=east] {O2}
(6,0.0) node[anchor=east] {O3}
(6,4) node[anchor=east] {O1}

;\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice question. I'll look over it tomorrow (it's nighttime here), but I don't think it could be easily done with the current implementation. But seems a valuable enhancement proposal, anyway.

Comment: I am considering it as a enhancement proposal; if you want you can open an issue at https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues

Comment: With current `circuitikz` you cannot achieve this. However, you can use `tikz's` stock `ciruit` option to achieve it. Nevertheless, a very useful question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fresh new `circuitikzgit` [uploaded minutes ago](http://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/), you can now do this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,3) node[american and port] (A)  {P1};
    \node at (A.bin 1) [ocirc, left]{} ;
    \begin{scope}
        \ctikzset{tripoles/american or port/height=1.6}
        \draw (A.out) -- ++(0.5,0) node[american or port,
        number inputs=5, anchor=in 1] (B)  {P2};
        \node at (B.bin 3) [ocirc, left]{} ;
    \end{scope}
    \draw (0,1.5) node[american or port] (C)  {P3};
    \node at (C.bin 2) [ocirc, left]{} ;
    \draw (C.out) |- (B.in 2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: output from he above snippet]

See: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/166 and https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/168

Comment: when will it be available in CTAN?

Comment: @Raaja I am completing a couple of things more (basically, manual overhaul and fillable shapes) and then I'll do a release. Three to five weeks, if RL doesn't create problems... ;-)

Comment: Good to know! Because, it seems many are interested in creating big-logic circuits with `ciruittikz` (see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480034/how-to-draw-a-big-logic-circuit-with-many-inputs-in-latex/480039#480039). And, I think this is a really nice contribution indeed :).