# How to draw a big logic circuit with many inputs in latex

Tags: circuitikz

how can we draw logic circuits with 128 inputs without showing all the input that means we can draw a logic diagram with showing of 3 or 4 bits as input but how can we draw it 128 inputs with labeling of 1 or 2 inputs and other will be so on till 127 (without labeling) and 128th bit should be labeled .

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a sketch of what you want, and **most importantly**, a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/156344) showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

First of all welcome to TeX.SE, from next time please show us what you have tried so far. We generally don't prefer `do-it-for-me` class of questions.

To begin your answer with, you can easily achieve this with `circuits` and `positioning` within `tikzlibrary`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,circuits.logic.IEC, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[minimum height=0.75cm] 
\node[and gate US, draw,logic gate inputs=nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn] (A) {}; 
\foreach \a in {1,...,128}
\draw (A.input \a) -- ([xshift=-2cm]A.input \a); 
\draw (A.output) -- ([xshift=2cm]A.output);
% naming the nodes
\node [left = 2.1cm of A.input 1] (n1) {1};
\node [left = 2.1cm of A.input 2] (n2) {2};
\node [left = 2.1cm of A.input 126] (n3) {126};
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

However, with `ciruittikz`, it is worth looking at:

[Is it possible to implement multiple input logic ports with circuitikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372993/is-it-possible-to-implement-multiple-input-logic-ports-with-circuitikz)

[How to invert Logic Gate input in Circuitikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479365/how-to-invert-logic-gate-input-in-circuitikz#comment1211267_479365)

Answer (score 1):

I think that, under the point of view of readability, a 128-port anything is too much. If you use the new (unreleased) version of `circuitikz` (you can find a [snapshot in the github page](https://circuitikz.github.io/circuitikz/))  you are limited to a (still unreadable in my opinion) 16 pins.

I would do something like the following, and textually mark the wires that go to the big or with some kind of symbol... like this

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikzgit}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    ]
    \ctikzset{logic ports origin=center}
    \draw(0,0) node[dipchip, num pins=14, no topmark, 
    external pins width=0, hide numbers](A){};
    \foreach \i/\l in {1/1, 2/2, 7/128} 
    \draw (A.bpin \i) node[right, font=\tiny]{\l} -- ++(-0.5,0) coordinate(my pin \i);
    \path (A.bpin 4) node[left]{$\vdots$};
    \draw (A.bpin 11) node[above right, font=\tiny]{out} -- ++(0.5,0);
    \path (A.center) node [american and port]{IC1};
    \draw (my pin 1) -- ++(-0.5,0) node[american xnor port, anchor=out]{}; 
    \draw (-4,-1) node[american xnor port](B){};
    \draw [->] (B.out) -- ++(0.5,0) node[right, align=left]{to IC1\\ pin 36};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]